# Can't we use scala flatMap method on List of integers (i.e) List[Int]?

Tags: scala

Can't we use scala flatMap method on List of integers (i.e) List[Int]?

I am getting compile time error  for the below code

```
object FlatMapExample {

  def main(args:Array[String])
  {    
   val numberList = List(1,2,3)
   val mappedList = numberList.map { elem => elem*2 }
   println(mappedList)

   val flatMappedList = numberList.flatMap { elem => elem*2 }//compile time error
   println(flatMappedList)

  }

 }
```

Compile time error:

```
 type mismatch ; found: Int required :scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?]
```

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to *flatten* here?

Comment: Do you want to sum elements, or what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`flatMap()` assumes you are returning a collection of values rather than a single element. Thus these would work:

```
val list = List(1,2,3)
list.flatMap(elem => List(elem * 2)) // List (2,4,6)
```

If you just want to multiply by two, use map.